# Importing libssh into Qt

Tags: c++, qt, libssh

I'm currently trying to import libssh into a Qt project I am working on. It appears that I have the library linked correctly as the project builds, but once I run the project it just crashes before anything really starts up. Which makes debugging difficult. If I comment out the line:

`my_ssh_session = ssh_new();`

Then everything runs as it should and no crash occurs. My .pro file looks like

```
QT += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

QT += sql
QT += script
QT += scripttools
QT += uitools

LIBS += -llibssh

INCLUDEPATH += $$quote(C:\libssh\include)

TARGET = white_wrapper
TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp \
        datafeeder.cpp \
        dbfeeder.cpp \
        xmlhelper.cpp \
        hiddevice.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h \
         datasource.h \
         datafeeder.h \
         dbfeeder.h \
         xmlhelper.h \
         hiddevice.h

FORMS += mainwindow.ui
```

After looking online it looks like the problem could be dlls but after running a dll dependency application it looks like I have all the dlls needed so I guess I'm at a lose and would love some input thanks.

Comment: What type of crash and what's the stack trace say?

Comment: @MrEricSir I'm not sure as the the program terminates on startup. When debugging a window pops up with the following text: "During startup program exited with code 0xc000007b."

Comment: Update I did find some answers here: [Qt creator and libssh](http://forum.qtfr.org/discussion/17738/qt-creator-et-libssh-probleme-de-fonctionnement).

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the same error message with libssh-0.7.1, Qt 5.2.1 and MinGW.

After some research it turned up that libssh
needs another two dynamic libraries which depends on: `libeay32.dll` and `zlib1.dll`. They are not included in libssh's distribution archive, therefore you have to download them yourself and copy next to libssh.dll (or somewhere on `$PATH`).

In my `.pro` file I have the following lines added (I installed libssh using their installer to Program Files (x86) directory):

```
# Libssh:
LIBS += -L$$PWD/'../../../../../Program Files (x86)/libssh/lib/' -lssh.dll
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/'../../../../../Program Files (x86)/libssh/include'
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/'../../../../../Program Files (x86)/libssh/include'
```

Now my Qt application works without problems.